# Two outputs in logstash. One for certain aggregations only

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to specify a second output of logstash in order to save certain aggregated data only. No clue how to achieve it at the moment. Documentation doesn't cover such a case.

At the moment I use a single input and a single output.

Input definition (`logstash-udp.conf`):

```
input { 
    udp { 
        port => 25000
        codec => json
        buffer_size => 5000
        workers => 2
    }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => [ "message", "API call happened" ]
  }

  aggregate {
    task_id => "%{example_task}"
    code => "
        map['api_calls'] ||= 0
        map['api_calls'] += 1
        map['message'] ||= event.get('message')
        event.cancel()
    "
    timeout => 60
    push_previous_map_as_event => true
    timeout_code => "event.set('aggregated_calls', event.get('api_calls') > 0)"
    timeout_tags => ['_aggregation']
  }
}
```

Output definition (`logstash-output.conf`):

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost"]
    manage_template => false
    index => "%{[@metadata][udp]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
  }
}
```

What I want to achieve now? I need to add a second, different aggregation (different data and conditions) which will save all the not aggregated data to Elasticsearch like now however aggregated data for this aggregation would be saved to Postgres. I'm pretty much stuck at the moment and searching the web for some docs/examples doesn't help.

Comment: I've never used the aggregate filter, so this comment might be wrong. But maybe if you use the `add_tag` param so that the message processed by the `aggregate` filter has a certain tag. Then you'd be able to use [conditionals](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.4/config-examples.html#using-conditionals) on that tag to add other filters/outputs.

Comment: Looks like a good idea but aggregation will eat all the raw data in order to aggregate it. I need not aggregated data as well. Looks like there's no solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using multiple pipelines: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/multiple-pipelines.html

This way you can have one pipeline for aggregation and second one for pure data.

Comment: I cannot use the same input twice so I would need to send logs twice. Cannot be done this way unfortunately.

Comment: Then according to [this elastic forum post](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/multiple-outputs/43746) you can have multiple outputs. If you add aggregation after first utput maybe it will be possible to do what you want to do.